# jQuery tagit - No such method 'add'

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, tag-it

Whilst searching for a away to add a tag to the jquery tagit, I came accross the following snippet:

```
$('.tagfilter').click(function(){
    $('#addtags').tagit('add', 'test value');
    return false;
});
```

However, this testing came accross this error:

> Error: no such method 'add' for tagit widget instance

This snippet worked for someone else, but not me... any ideas?

Comment: And if you bother to check the documentation of the version of the plugin you're using, do you find an `add` method?

Comment: Yes sorry, just found that whilst searching after asking question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try using :

```
$("#myTags").tagit("createTag", "brand-new-tag");
```

Source : https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown